# AngularJs multiple custom directives failure

Tags: angularjs

I have a web page with multiple custom directives, 2 for this example. Each directive loads an HTML page with a few `<a>` tags on it to be used for routing on my SPA. After I was done working on and testing one directive I started working on the other one and I couldn't get the links to work.
The directives DOES load the desired pages with the `<a>` links on them, bu the `<a>` links dont work:

```
<custom-directive-one></custom-directive-one>
<custom-directive-two></custom-directive-two>
```

In this fashion, `<custom-directive-two>` works fine, it's the first directive I finished working on. `<custom-directive-one>` does not work.

Until I do this

```
<custom-directive-one></custom-directive-one>
<!-- <custom-directive-two></custom-directive-two> -->
```

That way `<custom-directive-one>` works.

I'm using AngularJs version 1.6.2 .
Please help.

Here'a a Plunker example, can't get it to work though.
Would greatly appreciate it if someone could tell me why the Plunker example doesn't work: http://plnkr.co/edit/owbz2Yt9EXybTy9cfdsu?p=preview

Comment: It would be helpful to know what is in each of the directives. Please create an example (e.g. on [plunker](http://plnkr.co), [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), etc).

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: The expected behavior if for the directives to display the content of the HTML pages they are linked to, and they do display, and for the `<a>` tags on those pages to work, meaning link me to wherever. They dont. Unless I comment out the other directive. This being the ONLY change fixes problem. Also ZORE errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes to your code, including using a component instead of a directive, which is the recommended practice after Angular 1.5. You basically were not terminating you IIFE correctly, misspelled the name of one of your templates and had other minor issues.

```
(function(app) {

  //var app = angular.module('mainModule');

  app.component('customDirectiveOne', {
    templateUrl: 'linkListONE.html',
    controller: 'ListOneController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
  });

  app.component('customDirectiveTwo', {
    templateUrl: 'linkListTWO.html',
    controller: 'ListTwoController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
  });

  app.controller('ListOneController', function() {

  });
  app.controller('ListTwoController', function() {

  });

})(app);
```

Here's the final [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sHKQnuQvSfiC3C3Rj7UE).

Comment: Thanks, greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Changing directives to components solved it. Thanks again.